# Why can't I static_cast a tuple containing a void* to one containing a char*?

Tags: c++, casting, stdtuple

In the below code, I'm trying to `static_cast` a `std::tuple<void*, size_t>` to a `std::tuple<char*, size_t>`:

```
#include <tuple>

int main() {
  char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  size_t data_len = 3;

  const std::tuple<void*, size_t> a{static_cast<void*>(data), data_len};
  const std::tuple<char*, size_t> b =
      static_cast<const std::tuple<char*, size_t>>(a);
  printf("a's first element is %p\n", std::get<0>(a));
  printf("b's first element is %p\n", std::get<0>(b));
}
```

This code does not compile with `g++ -std=c++17` or `clang -std=c++17` (with recent GCC and Clang versions). In both cases, the compiler indicates that the static cast can't be done. Here's an example error from `clang`:

```
main.cc:9:13: error: no matching conversion for static_cast from 'const std::tuple<void *, size_t>' (aka 'const tuple<void *, unsigned long>') to 'const std::tuple<char *, size_t>'
      (aka 'const tuple<char *, unsigned long>')
            static_cast<const std::tuple<char*, size_t>>(a);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Given that a `void*` can be `static_cast` to a `char*`, shouldn't it also be possible to `static_cast` a `std::tuple<void*, size_t>` to a `std::tuple<char*, size_t>`? Is this just an oversight in the design of the STL or is there some underlying reason for it?

I ran into this issue while trying to find the root cause for [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769662/matching-c-style-array-passed-as-void-with-gmock).

What I'm trying to get out of this question is either "yes, that's weird, you should send a carefully worded email to the C++ standards committee suggesting that they fix this in a future C++ standard" or "no, it doesn't make sense to want this feature because X and Y".

Comment: A `Foo<X>` is a completely different type from a `Foo<Y>`  You can't `static_cast` between them.

Comment: Instead of showing us your attempted solution to a problem, what problem are you really trying to solve?  Also known as the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @NathanOliver, well, you can - if there is a conversion operator defined. Most obvious example `unique_ptr<X>` convertible to `unique_ptr<Y>` if `X*` convertible to `Y*`. Obviously, this is not the case with tuple, but worth mentioning for completness.

Comment: `std::is_convertible<void*, char*> == false` this cause the appropriate overloaded converting constructor of `std::tuple` be excluded.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this question describes the issue I ran into, it's related to googlemock and writing expectations on functions that take void pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769662/matching-c-style-array-passed-as-void-with-gmock

Comment: I'm failing to understand why you don't just make another tuple. I.e. the code and time invested in crafting a `std::tuple<char*,size_t>` from two `get`'s across the original tuple is *minuscule* compared to the apparent bent on somehow using `static_cast` instead. If there is no provided conversion (and there isn't), that won't work, so write around it.

Comment: @KerrickStaley -- *Given that a void* can be static_cast to a char*,* -- Note that you also can't cast a `vector<void*>` to a `vector<char *>`, or a `std::set<void *>` to a `std::set<char *>` or even a `Widget<void *>` to a `Widget<char *>`.  Those are all different types.  Unless you write the code to tell the compiler how to convert between the two types, then `static_cast` will not help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, that's helpful! I added an answer expanding on your suggestion of telling the compiler how to convert between the two types.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around this is to provide an intermediate class that can handle the conversion from `std::tuple<void*, size_t>` to `std::tuple<char*, size_t>` for you:

```
class TupleConverter : public std::tuple<char*, size_t> {
public:
  TupleConverter(const std::tuple<void*, size_t>& t) : std::tuple<char*, size_t>(
      static_cast<char*>(std::get<0>(t)), std::get<1>(t)) {}
};
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
const std::tuple<char*, size_t> b =
    static_cast<const TupleConverter>(a);
```